# Why does Aptana Studio Freeze when I copy and paste?

Tags: copy-paste, aptana3

Randomly, so not every time, when I paste something into my code on Aptana Studio 3.4.2 it will freeze up, giving me the cursor loading/wait icon, then will in a few seconds go into "Not Responding", so I minimize it and after a few more seconds it will flash and become active again. It's getting really annoying trying to work on something when this keeps happening.

Nothing else freezes up on my computer during this, just Aptana, and it only happens when Pasting into the page I'm working on. SO ANNOYING I'm about ready to ditch Aptana but I like it other than this annoyance... It just started recently...also if I reboot or wake the computer up from sleep (with app closed) then it is fine for awhile. But then it's much more common when it finally "kicks in".

So ...what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Same here... dealing width this bug for years now... really annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will help you, but try to increase the memory allocation
go to AptanaStudio3.ini and change to:
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m